# How to open camera in NDK of android 7.0 without system permission

Tags: java, android, camera, android-ndk, user-permissions

As we know, Google set more permission in Android 7.0. We can't user camera API directly in Android 7.0. 
Google has provided a library to developer named libcamera2ndk.so. But I'm confused that this library should take android system permission or needs system certificated signature for APK.
**ACameraManage_getCameraIdList()** shows numCameras is 0 when I run APK without any system permission.

Could you tell me some method about how to call libcamera2ndk.so without and system permission. I can't find any useful information in Google. 
Please help me.

Comment: If by "system permission", you mean `android.permission.CAMERA`, this should be required.

Comment: android.permission.CAMERA should add to AnroidManifest.xml. I mean system.uid to APK. System permission also means you device should be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, there is no way to do it, because if you could do this you could make pictures without the user know about it and that is a potentional security problem too.

As you can read the comments adding `android.permission.CAMERA` to your AndroidManifest.xml file should do it.

The other way is you request for permission in run time. There is the Google's documentation for it: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Runtime permissions are definitely what @wes should implement. If you don't want to implement these, you can always manually go into the permissions of the phone after you install the app and manually allow them through settings.